# Copy data from several tabs to one tab

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to repurpose [combine_data_from_all_sheets.vb](https://gist.github.com/danwagnerco/040402917376969bf362) to pull data from several tabs.

- Starting at O7:T7.
  The data starts in the same range for each tab.
- Some tabs may not have data and can be skipped.
  These tabs have formulas with double quotes instead.
- If there is data there won't be any blank spaces.
  If row 11 has data then so does 7, 8, 9 and 10

The areas that I'm having trouble with I wrote notes within the code, which is all of the text in full caps.

```vb
Option Explicit
Public Sub CombineDataFromAllSheets()

    Dim wksSrc As Worksheet, wksDst As Worksheet
    Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDst As Range
    Dim lngLastCol As Long, lngSrcLastRow As Long, lngDstLastRow As Long
    
    'Notes: "Src" is short for "Source", "Dst" is short for "Destination"
    
    'Set references up-front
    Set wksDst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AOD")
    lngDstLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksDst) '<- defined below
    lngLastCol = LastOccupiedColNum(wksDst) '<- defined below
    
    'Set the initial destination range
    Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngDstLastRow + 1, 1)
    
    'Loop through all sheets
    For Each wksSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    
        'Skip template sheet
        'WOULD LIKE TO ADD AN OR STATEMENT HERE, SOMETHING LIKE NAME <> "TEMPLATE" OR "LIST" THEN
        If wksSrc.Name <> "Template" Then
        
            'WOULD LIKE THIS TO SEARCH FOR LAST ROW WITH DATA THAT ISN'T DOUBLE QUOTES/A FORMULA WITH NO VISIBLE VALUES
            'Identify the last occupied row on this sheet
            lngSrcLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksSrc)
            
            'Store the source data then copy it to the destination range
            'WOULD LIKE TO ONLY COPY DATA IF THERE ARE VALUES IN CELLS, BUT MACRO IS PICKING UP CELLS WITH DOUBLE QUOTES
            'WOULD LIKE FOR THE MACRO TO ONLY COPY IF DATA EXISTS IN RANGE "O7:T7", IF DATA EXISTS HERE, CONTINUE TO COPY ALL DATA BELOW UNTIL CELLS ARE EMPTY (SKIP CELLS WITH "" AS VALUES)
            'WOULD LIKE TO COPY AND PASTE SPECIAL INSTEAD OF FORMULAS
            With wksSrc
                Set rngSrc = .Range("O7:T7")
                rngSrc.Copy Destination:=rngDst
            End With
            
            'Redefine the destination range now that new data has been added
            lngDstLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksDst)
            Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngDstLastRow + 1, 1)
            
        End If
    
    Next wksSrc
    
End Sub

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'INPUT       : Sheet, the worksheet we'll search to find the last row
'OUTPUT      : Long, the last occupied row
'SPECIAL CASE: if Sheet is empty, return 1
Public Function LastOccupiedRowNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim lng As Long
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
        With Sheet
            lng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                              After:=.Range("A1"), _
                              Lookat:=xlPart, _
                              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                              MatchCase:=False).Row
        End With
    Else
        lng = 1
    End If
    LastOccupiedRowNum = lng
End Function

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'INPUT       : Sheet, the worksheet we'll search to find the last column
'OUTPUT      : Long, the last occupied column
'SPECIAL CASE: if Sheet is empty, return 1
Public Function LastOccupiedColNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim lng As Long
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
        With Sheet
            lng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                              After:=.Range("A1"), _
                              Lookat:=xlPart, _
                              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                              MatchCase:=False).Column
        End With
    Else
        lng = 1
    End If
    LastOccupiedColNum = lng
End Function
```

Comment: Where specifically are errors occuring.

Comment: I should have clarified this, sorry.  The problem is the macro is only copying O7:T7.  I would like it to not copy this range if there isn't any data in these fields, and if there is data I want the code to continue copying below just row 7.  So if data exists in the range O7:T44, the macro will copy all of that.  Hopefully that makes sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

```
Option Explicit
Sub Pull_All_To_AOD()

    Dim wksSrc As Worksheet     'Source Sheet
    Dim wksDst As Worksheet     'Destination Sheet
    Dim rngSrc As Range         'Source Range
    Dim rngDst As Range         'Destination Range
    Dim RowCount As Long

    Set wksDst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AOD")
    
    'Iterate Worksheets
    For Each wksSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Skip Template, AOD, and empty sheets
        If wksSrc.Name <> "Template" And _
            wksSrc.Name <> "AOD" And _
            Trim(Application.WorksheetFunction.Concat(wksSrc.Range("O7:T7"))) <> "" Then
                'Find Data Size
                RowCount = wksSrc.Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 6
                'Copy Data to AOD sheet, next empty row
                wksDst.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(RowCount, 6).Value = _
                    wksSrc.Range("O7").Resize(RowCount, 6).Value
        End If
    Next wksSrc
End Sub
```

I think this is what you're looking for. Let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: Wow, this is perfect and also much easier for me to read/understand.  Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: I'm glad it helped, Is there anything you don't understand? Mark it correct if it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Data From Multiple Worksheets

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CombineDataWorksheets()

    ' Define constants.
    
    ' Source
    Const sFirstRowAddress As String = "O7:T7"
    ' The following two constants are related!
    Const sNameExceptionsList As String = "AOD,Template,List"
    Const sNameExceptionsDelimiter As String = ","
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "AOD"
    Const dFirstColumn As String = "A"
    
    ' Reference the workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    ' Reference the destination worksheet ('dws').
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    
    ' Write the number of worksheet rows to a variable ('wsrCount').
    Dim wsrCount As Long: wsrCount = dws.Rows.Count
    
    ' Using the destination worksheet with the source first row address,
    ' write the following three source properties to variables.
    
    Dim cCount As Long ' Source/Destination Columns Count
    Dim sfRow As Long ' Source First Row
    Dim scrgAddress As String ' Source Columns Range Address
    
    With dws.Range(sFirstRowAddress)
        cCount = .Columns.Count
        sfRow = .Row
        scrgAddress = .Resize(wsrCount - sfRow + 1).Address
    End With
    
    ' Reference the destination first row range.
    
    Dim dfrrg As Range ' Destination First Row Range
    
    ' Attempt to reference the last destination worksheet's row,
    ' the row of the bottom-most NON-EMPTY cell.
    ' Note that the Find method with its LookIn argument's parameter
    ' set to 'xlFormulas' will fail if the worksheet is filtered.
    ' It will NOT fail if rows or columns are just hidden.
    Dim dlCell As Range
    Set dlCell = dws.UsedRange.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    
    If dlCell Is Nothing Then ' the destination worksheet is empty
        Set dfrrg = dws.Cells(1, dFirstColumn).Resize(, cCount)
    Else ' the destination worksheet is not empty
        Set dfrrg = dws.Cells(dlCell.Row + 1, dFirstColumn).Resize(, cCount)
    End If
        
    ' Write the names from the name exception list to a zero-based string array,
    ' the name exceptions array ('sNameExceptions').
    Dim sNameExceptions() As String
    sNameExceptions = Split(sNameExceptionsList, sNameExceptionsDelimiter)
    
    ' Declare additional variables to be used in the loop.
    Dim sws As Worksheet ' Source Worksheet
    Dim srg As Range ' Source Range
    Dim slCell As Range ' Source Last Cell
    Dim rCount As Long ' Source/Destination Rows Count
    Dim drg As Range ' Destination Range
    
    ' Loop through the worksheets collection of the workbook...
    For Each sws In wb.Worksheets
        ' Check if the source name was NOT found in the name exceptions array.
        If IsError(Application.Match(sws.Name, sNameExceptions, 0)) Then
            ' Reference the source columns range, the range from the first
            ' source row range to the bottom-most worksheet row range.
            With sws.Range(scrgAddress)
                ' Attempt to reference the source worksheet's last row,
                ' the row of the bottom-most NON-BLANK cell.
                ' Note that the Find method with its LookIn argument's
                ' parameter set to 'xlValues' will fail if the worksheet
                ' is filtered, and even if rows or columns are just hidden.
                Set slCell = .Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
                ' Check if a source non-blank cell was found.
                If Not slCell Is Nothing Then ' non-blank cell found
                    ' Calculate the number of source/destination rows.
                    rCount = slCell.Row - sfRow + 1
                    ' Reference the source range.
                    Set srg = .Resize(rCount)
                    ' Reference the destination range.
                    Set drg = dfrrg.Resize(rCount)
                    ' Write the values from the source to the destination range.
                    drg.Value = srg.Value
                    ' Reference the next destination first row range.
                    Set dfrrg = dfrrg.Offset(rCount)
                'Else  ' non-blank cell not found; do nothing
                End If
            End With
        'Else ' worksheet name is in the name exceptions array; do nothing
        End If
    Next sws
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Data combined.", vbInformation

End Sub
```